# Largest Element with same Class

Tags: jquery, css

Got a quick one for ya!

Okay, assume we have a random number of divs all with the class "jello."
Each div would have an amount of text in it that could differ on each page load. So even though the 2nd "jello" div might be the widest now, next time it may be the fifth that is the widest.

How would we find the element with the largest width when using the class as a selector?

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Make an array of all the DIVs, sort the array on their widths, and then return the first element of the array.

Comment: @Barmar That's a clever idea.

Comment: Clever, but the simple loop in the answers is probably better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var max_width = 0;
var widest_div;
$('.jello').each(function() {
    var w = $(this).width();
    if (w > max_width) {
        max_width = w;
        widest_div = this;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is my answer. Thank you. I appreciate it. I will select this as answer when timer is up. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.jello').each(function() {
   //compare the width
});
```

Comment: Might mention that he should store the last width if it exceeds the current width.